# How do I delete a Project in Google Cloud Platform and bypass the 30 day hold?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, project

I am trying to create a new project, but I get an error indication I have reached my project quota, I have shut down/deleted multiple projects but there seems to be a 30 day period during which the project still exists and I still cant create a new project. Is there a way to bypass the 30 day hold?

Comment: What type of account do you have (free trial or paid)?

Comment: Thanks for the answers - there is no way currently to bypass the 30 delay. That being said Google was very responsive to request for adding to my quota allowance (less than 2 hours).  Thank you to Prajna Rai T for the links and suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Project quota is the number of projects you are allowed to create within your organization. This is a bit more special then resource quotas you see under the quota page. Partially because this quota is tied to your Org/Billing account, also because deletion of the project has a [30 day grace period](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects).

At the end of the 30-day period, the project and all of its resources are deleted and cannot be recovered. Until it is deleted, the project will count towards your project quota.

I recommend you to follow the project quota increase procedures:

[Request Billing Quota Increase](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#managing_project_quotas)

Further explanation about [project quotas](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6330231?hl=en).